# Sourcetree Stage hunk button missing

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I just created a new branch to work on a bug and checked out the branch in Sourcetree (to a new folder).  I updated 1 file and added 1 new file.  In the Sourcetree Log/History I only see the updated file.  If I select the updated file, the changes show in hunks, however, the "stage hunk" button is not showing (only reverse hunk is showing).  I'm using version 2.4.6.0 of Sourcetree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the "File Status" tab (along the bottom).  If no files are listed, select "Pending" from the drop down menu near the top (it was set to 'conflicts').